# Javascript vs JavaBean in speed

Tags: javascript, performance, jsp, javabeans

I have a question pertaining to JSP development. My servlet reaches a point where my simple Java classes cannot help me with my website, and Javascript takes over. The problem is that the data is very large, and with Javascript it is very slow. Would using Javabeans speed it up? By how much? How can javascript get and pass values to Javabeans? Is Javabeans dynamic like javascript, or is it executed on page refresh like JSP? Or am I wrong in general(I think I am) 
So many questions please answer.

Comment: What are you thinking of when you say you would use javabeans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing a good thing and targeting a significant progress by willing to write both a complex server-side part and client-side javascript code, but as I can see from your questions (sorry if I'm wrong) your missing the point with server and client interaction.

At first let's take a look at overal HTTP protocol which regulates how modern web-apps work. According to HTTP architecture all interaction between client (represented as a browser application at your local machine) and server (represented as a servlet container with java classes running on it - which is tomcat/jboss/etc - remote computer) is done through simple reques(question from browser)-response(answer from server) cycles. Client asks by URL for some information, server gives this information to client, after client process (reads) retrieved information (which could have not only images,video,audio,text but also program code in form of javascript) and asks for some more specific information from the server in next question (http-request). While giving answers (processing requests) you can store an intermediate information between request-response cycles either at client side (in browser - cookies that holds specific information for various web-sites) or at server side (in server sessions, databases, server files for various web-site users).  Hope this part is so far understandable.

Java performs totally at the server-side, so any sort of JavaBeans either simple JavaBeans (or POJO - plain old java objects)  or EJB (enterprise java beans - much complexed solution available at enterpirse java platform)  are working and living totally at the server side and lives in session or application scopes. In other words user can pass some argument through HTTP GET/POST/PUT/DELETE methods to your servlet/jsp which are reading those params and modifying beans information according to passed&parsed data from the user.

JavaScript by turns executes totally at the client-side level. JS can save information in browser cookies (or localstorage - introduced in html5) which are basically key-value data-pairs stored in client's browser for a specific site distinguished by its URL.

JavaScript is used only to save information during only quick request-response interactions in other words you can treat JS storage being totally lost after a user closes his browser window (ends up his work with a site). While Server-side information is stored much longer (roughly forever) and pertains between working sessions with a site.

So from this point of view you can always created a thin client (almost no JavaScript) which  totaly relies on server-side logic and java beans. But any small operation with your web-app in that case of a thin client would take quite a long time, because it requires a server-round trip. In other words you app will be slow. So to speed-up your web-apps you can shift some operations from server-side java to client-side javascript so they can be performed with a less server-request. As an example imagine that you are writing a calculator web-app: you can either create a html-form and for each operation (+-*/) send a request to the server (to java part), or you can create a native JS-app and each operation will be performed by JavaScript without server-side trip (in that case your appication will be much faster).

I recommend you to read more information on how HTTP (and REST - an architecture behind HTTP protocol) actually works. For example [this tutorial.](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-beginners-introduction-to-http-and-rest/)

Comment: thanks, very insightfull response.